# Encoding URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, uri

I have a string with URL data, ex: "http://www.amazon.com" and I would like to receive "http%3A%2F%2Famazon.com".

After reading different posts I am using this command:

```
irb(main):025:0> require 'open-uri'
=> true
irb(main):026:0> URI.encode("http://www.amazon.com")
=> "http://www.amazon.com"
irb(main):027:0>
```

As you can see I receive my string instead of "http%3A%2F%2Famazon.com".

I really appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
CGI.escape("http://www.amazon.com")
 #=> "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com"
```